# jQuery verificação campo banco de dados php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte botão:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><? echo $titulo; ?></button>
```

Este botão, envia uma ação de formulário, com os dados preenchidos.

E também tenho o seguinte campo:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="con_email" id="con_email" placeholder="E-mail da Consultora" value="<? if(isset($dados->con_email)){ echo $dados->con_email; } ?>" required>
```

Preciso que, ao pressionar o botão de submit, faça uma verificação, se este e-mail já existe no banco de dados. Sei que é possível elaborar isto em jQuery, porém, não sei por onde começar a verificação.

Pensei apenas na hora de enviar, faço a busca via php e retorno true ou false, retornando, true, eu apenas chamo uma modal, retornando false, chamo o ajax pra insert no banco de dados, usando o método get ou post.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu posso elaborar este jQuery?

Comment: A sua lógica esta certa, agora é detalhe de implementação, depende da forma que você costuma fazer, em suma será uma requisição para validar o email e outra para enviar o formulário. e a do formulário depende do email.

Comment: Exatamente, mas penso em validar, se vier true (1), eu imprimo a mensagem se não eu faço a inclusão, via jquery mesmo.. o php eu trabalho ele, conforme a necessidade, o que eu não sei desenvolver seria este jquery. :)

Comment: Eu faço tudo funcionar primeiro sem jquery/Ajax, com todas as validações necessárias no server side, depois eu faço o Ajax enviar o form original e trato o retorno, o resultado final é que tudo funciona exatamente igual mesmo estando sem js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que seu html esteja assim ou algo parecido:

```
<form action="gravar.php" method="post" id="formGravar">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="con_email" id="con_email" placeholder="E-mail da Consultora" value="<? if(isset($dados->con_email)){ echo $dados->con_email; } ?>" required>
    <button type="button" id="btnCheck" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><? echo $titulo; ?></button>

</form>
```

O javascript você pode fazer assim:

```
<script>
$("#btnCheck").on('click', function(){
    $.post('checar_email.php', {email: $("#con_email").val()}, function(r){
        if(r == '0'){
            $("#formGravar").submit();
        }else{
            alert('e-mail já existe na base');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

O javascript irá atuar no botão sem trabalhar com o formulário inicialmente.
Irá enviar um ajax para o PHP "checar_email.php" onde você deve receber o $_POST['email'] e fazer a checagem na base se tem ou não o e-mail digitado.
Caso tiver você retorna "1" e mostra um alert e caso não "0" irá dar um submit no formulário que envia para o "gravar.php" que irá inserir o e-mail na base.

Arquivo "checar_email.php" fica algo parecido com isso:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

//Aqui é uma função que irá se conectar a base e verificar se existe o e-mail ou não. 
//Você pode substituir isso pelo seu método de validação
$check = checarEmail($email);

if($check){
    echo '1';
}else{
    echo '0';
}
?>
```

Vale lembrar que o exemplo acima é muito básico e não tem nenhum tipo de segurança. Recomendo você trabalhar na segurança dos dados vindos do formulário para evitar SQL injections e também trabalhar no tratamento de erros.

Espero ter ajudado.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Creio que seria isto, vou testar aqui p ver... mas como é um sistema interno, já com validação de login, sessions e também permissões de módulos, creio que não terei maiores problemas. Agradeço sua ajuda, posto notícias daqui um pouco.

Comment: Olá, este jQuery nem chegou na validação... Ele passa direto.

Comment: Você diz q ao clicar no botão não faz a checagem? 
O botão tem q ser type="button" senão o form de gravação é enviado junto com o ajax.

Comment: Gente, e eu achando que a pessoa estava usando CodeIgniter...

Answer (score 0):

Vc só precisa de um método controlando essa requisição **(com segurança)**. Tente assim:

**CONTROLLER:**

```
function check_email() {
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','trim|required|valid_email');
  if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
    show_error('Dados inválidos!');
  }
  else{
    echo json_encode($this->nome_model->check_email());
 }
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
function check_email(){
    $email = $this->db->escape_str($this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $query = $this->db->get(self::TABELA);
    if(!empty($query->result_array())){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#id_do_botao').click(function(){
 $.post("nome_do_controller/check_email", {
 email: $('#con_email').val()
},
 function (resp) {
  var response = jQuery.parseJSON(resp);
  if(response === 'true'){
   $('#id_do_modal').modal('show');
  }
 });
}
```

Basicamente: o evento onclick do botão chama o método 'check_email()' do controlador via POST passando o valor do campo 'con_email'; O controlador responde 'true' ou 'false' com base no método 'check_mail()' do model; JQuery usa a resposta para mostrar ou não mostrar seu modal.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia. Estou com problemas no codigo Jquery postado por ShutUpMagda. 
Continuo o POST ou crio um novo POST com os meus códigos (controller, model, view e jquery )?